# Melt DataFrame with two value variables

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with inventory and purchases across multiple stores and regions. I am trying to stack the dataframe using melt, but I need to have two value columns, inventory and purchases, and can't figure out how to do that. The dataframe looks like this:

```
Region   |   Store   |  Inventory_Item_1   |  Inventory_Item_2  |  Purchase_Item_1  |  Purchase_Item_2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
 North         A             15                    20                 5                     6
 North         B             20                    25                 7                     8
 North         C             18                    22                 6                     10
 South         D             10                    15                 9                     7
 South         E             12                    12                 10                    8
```

The format I am trying to get the dataframe into looks like this:

```
  Region   |   Store   |      Item              |  Inventory   |   Purchases      
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   North        A         Inventory_Item_1             15             5
   North        A         Inventory_Item_2             20             6
   North        B         Inventory_Item_1             20             7
   North        B         Inventory_Item_2             25             8    
   North        C         Inventory_Item_1             18             6
   North        C         Inventory_Item_2             22             10
   South        D         Inventory_Item_1             10             9
   South        D         Inventory_Item_2             15             7
   South        E         Inventory_Item_1             12             10
   South        E         Inventory_Item_2             12             8
```

This is what I have written, but I don't know how to create columns for Inventory and Purchases. Note that my full dataframe is considerably larger (50+ regions, 140+ stores, 15+ items).

```
df_1 = df.melt(id_vars = ['Store','Region'],value_vars = ['Inventory_Item_1','Inventory_Item_2'])
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: so your aim is to loose info abot purchases? (info about Purchase_Item_1 and Purchase_Item_2 gets lost)

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Purchase_Item_I and Purchase_Item_2 are just the purchases for Items 1 and 2. That data is in the 'Purchases' column.

Comment: That was actually the point - it should not be named "Inventory_Item_1", ... - but just "Item_1", "Item_2", ... otherwise very confusing - see my solution

Answer (score 1):

I would do these with hierarchical indexes on the rows and columns.

For the rows, you can `set_index(['Region', 'Store'])` easily enough.

You have to get a little tricksy for the columns though. Since you need access to the non-index columns that result from setting the index on Region and Store, you need to `pipe` it to a custom function that builds the desired tuples and creates a name multi-level column index.

After that, you can stack the columns into the row index and optionally reset the full row index to make everything a normal column again.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Region': ['North', 'North', 'North', 'South', 'South'],
    'Store': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'Inventory_Item_1': [15, 20, 18, 10, 12],
    'Inventory_Item_2': [20, 25, 22, 15, 12],
    'Purchase_Item_1': [5, 7, 6, 9, 10],
    'Purchase_Item_2': [6, 8, 10, 7, 8]
})


output = (
    df.set_index(['Region', 'Store'])
      .pipe(lambda df:
        df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split('_', n=1, expand=True), axis='columns')
      )
      .rename_axis(['Status', 'Product'], axis='columns')
      .stack(level='Product')
      .reset_index()
)
```

Which gives me:

```
Region Store Product  Inventory  Purchase
 North     A  Item_1         15         5
 North     A  Item_2         20         6
 North     B  Item_1         20         7
 North     B  Item_2         25         8
 North     C  Item_1         18         6
 North     C  Item_2         22        10
 South     D  Item_1         10         9
 South     D  Item_2         15         7
 South     E  Item_1         12        10
 South     E  Item_2         12         8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor) :

```
 # install the latest dev version of pyjanitor
 # pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git

 import janitor
df.pivot_longer(
    index=["Region", "Store"],
    names_to=(".value", "item"),
    names_pattern=r"(Inventory|Purchase)_(.+)",
    sort_by_appearance=True,
)

  Region    Store   item    Inventory   Purchase
0   North   A       Item_1      15      5
1   North   A       Item_2      20      6
2   North   B       Item_1      20      7
3   North   B       Item_2      25      8
4   North   C       Item_1      18      6
5   North   C       Item_2      22      10
6   South   D       Item_1      10      9
7   South   D       Item_2      15      7
8   South   E       Item_1      12      10
9   South   E       Item_2      12      8
```

It works by passing a regex, containing groups to `names_pattern` parameter. The '.value' in `names_to` ensures that `Inventory` and `Purchase` are kept as column headers while the other group(`Item_1` and `Item_2`) are collated into a new group `item`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to there by these steps:

```
# please always provide minimal working code - we as helpers and answerers 
# otherwise have to invest extra time to generate beginning working code
# and that is unfair - we already spend enough time to solve the problem:
df = pd.DataFrame([
["North","A",15,20,5,6],
["North","B",20,25,7,8],
["North","C",18,22,6,10],
["South","D",10,15,9,7],
["South","E",12,12,10,8]], columns=["Region","Store","Inventory_Item_1","Inventory_Item_2","Purchase_Item_1","Purchase_Item_2"])

# melt the dataframe completely first
df_final = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Region', 'Store'], value_vars=['Inventory_Item_1', 'Inventory_Item_2', 'Purchase_Item_1', 'Purchase_Item_2'])

# extract inventory and purchase sub data frames
# they have in common the "variable" column (the item number!)
# so let it look exactly the same in both data frames by removing
# unnecessary parts
df_inventory = df_final.loc[[x.startswith("Inventory") for x in df_final.variable],:]
df_inventory.variable = [s.replace("Inventory_", "") for s in df_inventory.variable]
df_purchase = df_final.loc[[x.startswith("Purchase") for x in df_final.variable],:]
df_purchase.variable = [s.replace("Purchase_", "") for s in df_purchase.variable]

# deepcopy the data frames (just to keep old results so that you can inspect them)
df_purchase_ = df_purchase.copy()
df_inventory_ = df_inventory.copy()

# rename the columns to prepare for merging
df_inventory_.columns = ["Region", "Store", "variable", "Inventory"]
df_purchase_.columns = ["Region", "Store", "variable", "Purchase"]

# merge by the three common columns
df_final_1 = pd.merge(df_inventory_, df_purchase_, how="left", left_on=["Region", "Store", "variable"], right_on=["Region", "Store", "variable"])

# sort by the three common columns
df_final_1.sort_values(by=["Region", "Store", "variable"], axis=0)
```

This returns

```
  Region Store variable  Inventory  Purchase
0  North     A   Item_1         15         5
5  North     A   Item_2         20         6
1  North     B   Item_1         20         7
6  North     B   Item_2         25         8
2  North     C   Item_1         18         6
7  North     C   Item_2         22        10
3  South     D   Item_1         10         9
8  South     D   Item_2         15         7
4  South     E   Item_1         12        10
9  South     E   Item_2         12         8
```